# How long does UK citizenship application take?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

How long does it usually take between submitting the application for the UK citizenship (assuming using NCS, correct documents, etc.) and getting the answer?

I mean specifically application AN (5 year stay, naturalisation).

Comment: What is an AN application? Does that stand for something? It seems hard to find the full name when I google it. Also check out the timelines of posters here: http://www.immigrationboards.com/british-citizenship/ Note that timelines vary from person to person.

Comment: Vagish: https://www.gov.uk/becoming-a-british-citizen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This booklet](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/318570/2902467-Guide_AN_v1_0.pdf) from the government's site states 2-4 weeks.

Answer (score -1):

The booklet states 2-4 weeks for acknowledgement of the application...this is different from the decision which can take longer I assume.

Comment: Do you have a link or picture of this booklet?